# Mapping array of strings into array of specific object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a problem to make an array of strings into objects of url paths (for breadcrumbs)

I have this array :

`const array = ['visit', 'schedule', 'validator']`

What I tried :

```
  const routeArray = array.map((b) => ({
    label: b,
    route: `/${b}`,
  }))
  console.log(routeArray)
```

result :

```
   [  
     {label: "visit", route: "/visit"},
     {label: "schedule", route: "/schedule"},
     {label: "validator", route: "/validator"},
   ]
```

what I want to achieve :

```
  [
    {label: "visit", route: "/visit"},
    {label: "schedule", route: "/visit/schedule"},
    {label: "validator", route: "/visit/schedule/validator"}
  ]
```

Any help ?

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far, please? Please notice that people are expected to [make some effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/14201528) to solve the problem by their own before asking here.

Comment: @secan Sure! I edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate the String while going through the array:

```js
const array = ['visit', 'schedule', 'validator'];

let route = "";

const result = array.map(label => {
    route += '/' + label;
    return { label, route };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this out and let me know if this is what you were looking for:

```
const array = ['visit', 'schedule', 'validator'] 

const newArray = array.map((entry, index) => {
  const route = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < index + 1; i++) {
    route.push(array[i]);
  }
  
  return {
    label: entry,
    route: route.join('/'),
  };
});

console.log(newArray);
```

In this approach, I loop through `as many` elements `as the order` of the `current element` of `array`, `pushing` them into the `route array`. When creating the object properties, I `join` the `elements of route` separated by '/'.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.map()`, `Array.prototype.slice()` and `Array.prototype.join()` can be your best friends, here:

```js
const input = ['visit', 'schedule', 'validator'];

const output = input.map((item, index) => {
  return {
    label: item,
    route: '/' + input.slice(0, index + 1).join('/')
  }
});

// test
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Simple and effective! Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we can do this using the reduce method:

```
const arr = ["visit", "schedule", "validator"];
const res = arr.reduce((acc, curr, idx, self) => {

    // Our route property of our needed data structure
    const route = `/${self.slice(0, idx)}${idx > 0 ? "/" + curr : curr}`;

    // Our new object
    const obj = { label: curr, route };
    return [...acc, obj];
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: The expected output matches one-to-one with the input; using `Array.prototype.reduce()` for this case would add unnecessary complexity, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using a for loop. You need to have a variable which tracks your `incrementing` route and persists over loop iterations.

```js
const array = ['visit', 'schedule', 'validator'];

let ansArray = [];
let incrVal = '';
for(let i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++){
let ans = incrVal + '/' + array[i];
ansArray.push({'label' : array[i], 'route' : ans});
incrVal = ans;
}

console.log(ansArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = ['visit', 'schedule', 'validator'];

const results = array.map((item, index, arr) => {
  
  return {
    label: item,
    route: '/' + arr.slice(0, index + 1).join('/'),
  };
});

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ***reduce*** array method

```js
const array = ["visit", "schedule", "validator"];
const res = array.reduce((acc, curr, idx, arr) => {
  acc.push({
    label: curr,
    route:'/'+ arr.slice(0, idx + 1).join('/')
  })
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the shortest way to do this:

```js
const input = ["visit", "schedule", "validator"];
const res = input.map((label, i, arr) => ({
  label,
  route: '/' + arr.slice(0, i + 1).join("/")
}));

console.log(input);
console.log(res);
```